# How to test screenprops in react native using Jest

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, testng, react-props

I have a class that extends from **Component** in my React Native project. I use this class in other classes **render** and I pass **screen props** with it:

```
class OtherClass extend Component {

render() {
return (
         <MyCustomComponent screenprops ={{number : this.state.number}}
   })

}
```

Now I am using Jest to write tests. I was able to write a test for the component class without the screen props:

```
test('MyCustomComponent renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(this.MyCustomComponent);
});
```

But I don't know how test the screenprops and use them in my test. 
I've search a lot but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this :

```
test('renders correctly', () => {

  const propsLink = {
    screenProps: {
      arrayProp: [
        {
          v1: true,
          v2: "my value 1",
        },
        {
          v1: false,
          v2: "my value 2",
        }
      ],
      number: 1
    }
  }

  renderer.create(<MyCustomComponent {...propsLink} />)
});
```